# UI Layout, fragments and different content

Tags: android-fragments, android

I'm studying fragments and "Multiple devices support". Depending on device type, orientation and dimension, it's possible to define multiple layout using fragments and re-using written code. During the develop of an app, I wrote down my desired UI for tablet devices, as described in the following screenshot:

[image: design]

The activity contains two fragments and displays TAB menu navigation. Every TAB menu navigation contains different menu entry (listview).
When clicking on a menu's item on fragment 1, I need to refresh the fragment number 2.
Fragment 2 is composed by a presentation and, below, a listview or another presentation.
Every menu's item could have different layout:

- 1-Presentation, image, another presentation
- 2-No presentation, listview
- 3-Presentation, listview
- 4-etc.

Studying examples (samples) provided with google-sdk, fragment 2 have always the same layout. How it's possible to tell fragment 2 to load different layout depending on menu's item clicked?

My answer is: I need a fragment class for every different layout. When the user click on an item of fragment 1, the fragment manager should replace and commit the correct fragment. Is this answer correct?

All fragment logic will be on my activity, replacing the correct fragment depending on item selected (position and category); simple ex:

```
   @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int category, int position) {
            if (position==0){
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frag, new FirstActionFragment(), "FirstMenuClicked");
            ft.commit();
        }
        else {
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frag, new SecondActionFragment(), "secondMenuClicked");
            ft.commit();
        }
  }
```

Is my layout idea improvable? Should I change something on my design to correctly implement fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem

https://github.com/theomega/ActivatedStateDemo

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.